# Asymptotes to tanh

Tags: calculus

I am new to this site. I have just started reading hyperbolic functions in calculus. I wanted to know if we could derive the shape of $y= \tanh x$ using derivative tests ( if yes, how?). By shape I mean,

1. It has two horizontal asymptotes at $x=1$, $x=-1$.
2. it is inverted $u$ in shape when $x$ belongs to $\mathbb{R_+}$
3. It is $U$ shaped when $x$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}_{-}$

Comment: The shape of the curve is called a sigmoid.

Comment: The curve doesn't look anything like a sigma.

Comment: Sigmoid is not the same as sigma...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asymptotes $y=\pm1$ are immediate from $\tanh x = \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}$ by noticing that the first terms dominate towards $+\infty$ giving $\frac{1+0}{1-0} = +1$ and the second terms dominate towards $-\infty$ giving $\frac{0+1}{0-1} = -1$. I'm not sure you can use a derivative test to establish this, though.

For the others, just note that $$(\tanh x)'=\frac1{\cosh^2 x}$$
$$(\tanh x)'' = \frac{-2\sinh x}{\cosh^3 x}$$

Recall that $\cosh x$ is always positive, and that $\sinh x $ has the sign of $x$. Thus:

-- The first derivative is always positive (so the function is strictly increasing everywhere).

-- The second derivative is positive for $x<0$ (so the function is  concave up there), and is negative for $x>0$ (so the function is concave down there).

That's pretty much everything you mentioned, right?

Answer (score 0):

I am quite confused of your question. Maybe it will help if you have a look at the graph of $\tanh x$  and of its derivative.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tanh+x

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sech%5E2(x)

There is nothing like this "shape" you mentioned, but according to the curve of the derivative, you can imagine how the function will behave (very roughly speaking). Check the definitions of the derivative from your class and see what does it mean that when the derivative is positive, gets larger, vice versa.

Comment: I think OP just means "concave up" and "concave down" when he says "U-shaped" and "inverted-U-shaped"

Comment: ah, ok.. this makes more sense, thx